# Нужна помощь в настройке джойстика для мобильной игры на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я вроде бы правильно написал скрипт для управления джойстиком , но когда запускаю проект и пытаюсь пошевелить им , то персонаж двигается только в одну сторону. По координате x. Мне нужно , чтобы он двигался и по x , и по y координатам. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float horizontalMove;
    private float verticalMove;
    public float jumpForce;
    public Joystick joystick;
    public Type type;
    public enum Type { PC, Joystick, Buttons }
    private bool facingRight = true;
    private bool isGrounted;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask ground;
    private Animator anim;
    public GameObject buttons;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (type == Type.PC)
        {
            horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        }
        if (type == Type.Joystick)
        {
            horizontalMove = joystick.Horizontal;
        }

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalMove * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (!facingRight && horizontalMove > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (facingRight && horizontalMove < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        if (horizontalMove == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("run", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("run", true);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float verticalMove = joystick.Vertical;

        if (!facingRight && verticalMove > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (facingRight && verticalMove < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        if (verticalMove == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("run", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("run", true);
        }

    }

    public void Move(float move)
    {
        if (type == Type.Buttons)
        {
            horizontalMove = move;
        }
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (type == Type.Buttons && isGrounted)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scale = transform.localScale;
        Scale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scale;

        if (horizontalMove < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
        }
        else if (horizontalMove > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В апдейте вы рассчитываете ускорение по вертикали, но не присваиваете его `rb.velocity`, поэтому объект и не двигается по оси Y. Вообще, вынесите код, отвечающий за движение, в отдельный метод, чтобы не было такого дубляжа кода как у вас и не нужно было делать изменения в разных участках кода, чтобы изменить одну часть логики. Код инпута тоже нужно вынести в отдельный класс, чтобы не было проверок на то геймпадом сейчас управляет игрок или клавиатурой, паттерн [стратегия](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/3.1.php) вам в помощь.